# Compactification of Bosonic Closed Strings on $T^2$ and $T^3$

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, compactification, critical-phenomena

I am looking for a text to explain compactification of bosonic closed strings on $T^2$ and $T^3$ by focusing on its gauge groups enhancement. In fact, I want to know in each case ($T^2$ and $T^3$) how many massless fields appear and what are their spins (scalar or vector and...)?

Answer (score 0):

If we know the field content of the Bosonic closed strings, then we can compactify on say $T^2, T^3$ or any compact manifolds. Rules are very easy to understand. Start with metric (notation M, N-all spacetime, $\mu,\nu$ are uncompactified spacetime, m,n are compactified ones. )

1. $G_{MN}$- so $G_{\mu\nu}$ are tensors or metric on uncompactified space. $G_{mn}$ are tensor on from compact ones but scalars from spacetime, $G_{m\mu}$ are vectors.
2. Similar things can be done for vectors $V_{M}= V_{\mu}$ is vector+ ($M-\mu$ ) scalars corresponding to the direction along compact directions.
3. Similarly, any $p$ form can be decomposed.